# fixer l'eau - la signification

Tags: sens, expressions

> De l'herbe verte pousse sur la terre ocre et brune. Le but : fixer l'eau, denréee qui se fait de plus en plus rare.

Fixer l'eau - cela veut dire quoi dans ce contexte?

Comment: Je suppose que tu connais le sens du mot « fixer », d'ailleurs il est facile de le trouver dans un dictionnaire. Ce que tu veux je suppose c'est une explication scientifique du phénomène. French Language n'est pas un forum de discussion il ne répond qu'à des questions portant sur la langue française.  Il est  facile de trouver sur internet une réponse à ta question.  Tu peux aussi poser la question - en anglais - sur un autre site de Stack Exchange: [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the French Language. Answering it requires scientific knowledge.

Comment: J'avais omis l'explication simple du terme, c'est à dire ce qu'il signifie sans détails techniques ; ce terme est néanmoins un terme spécialisé. (Je ne crois pas que l'on ait vraiment à fermer la question.)

Comment: Il n'existe pas de véritable raison pour fermer cette question : on trouve 63 cas de termes classés sous le label « Pédol. » dans le TLFi et par exemple le terme «  action tampon » dans ce domaine même, ce qui est très similaire à « fixer l'eau ».

Answer (score 4):

En gros cela veut dire « retenir l'eau dans le sol », la forcer à rester dans le sol.

Ce qu'il y a de plus probable est que ce but de fixer l'eau c'est  de ralentir l'évaporation ; l'herbe couvrant le sol offre un paravent à la terre nue ; de plus, les plantes absorbent une quantité d'eau qu'elles préservent.

Le même terme s'utilise pour le métabolisme du corps humain ; le sel par exemple est dit fixer l'eau dans le corps, la raison de cela étant que le sel est un composé hydrophile (qui attire l'eau) ([réf.](http://forum.davidmanise.com/index.php?topic=849.0)).

Ce qui semble probable apparait ne pas avoir beaucoup d'importance ; l'herbe servirait surtout à empêcher le ruissellement et ses racines à augmenter le pouvoir d'infiltration de l'eau dans le sol (voir cet article sur la [pédologie](https://www.u-picardie.fr/beauchamp/mst/eau-sol.htm), chercher le mot « rétention »).